# Stable Classloader for Akka testing in SBT

Tags: sbt, akka, classloader

When launching sbt in interactive mode, running the test task once succeeds but the second time it fails with a class loading exception.

The Akka team suggests that I should initialize my ActorSystem with a stable classloader.

What's the right classloader to use and how can I retrieve it in my tests?

Answer (score 2):

I have managed to get my test working by initialing the ActorSystem with a classloader from a class **NOT** in my test source folder like so:

```
  implicit lazy val actorSystem = ActorSystem(actorSystemName, classLoader = Some(classOf[MyClassInMainSrcClasspath].getClassLoader)
```

This solved the issue